# How do you use libtool to create .a files (static libraries) on Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, static-libraries, libtool

When it comes to using the terminal to build libraries manually and such I unfortunately do not have much experience and I'm stuck a bit here.

I've downloaded a library for objective-c which came with makefiles and such.

I can see that the folder also contains an executable file called "libtool", I did some searching and I suppose this is the program I have to use to build the neccessary **.a** files? Unfortunately I couldn't really find any useful article for this that seemed to work.

The folder for the library contains some **.sh** files, **.pc** files and also some **.la** files, but I'm a bit unsure of which ones I have to use as input to the libtool program to compile them into a **.a** file.

So my question is what files do you have to input into *libtool* to compile them into the necessary *.a* file? And what commands do you use exactly to accomplish this?

Thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First a little introduction to static libraries:

Static libraries in Unix environments (like Mac OSX, and Linux too) are actually just an archive of object files created by the [`ar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ar.1.html) command line program.

That is what the `.a` extension stands for: Archive.

To create a static library with some object files you can use the command like this:

```
ar crv libmy_library.a objectfile1.o objectfile2.o
```

---

As for your actual question, `libtool` should be called automatically from the makefile, creating the library, which is the file ending in `.la`. However, this is not the real library, the real library is in a hidden directory. You can find it by doing e.g.

```
find . -name '*.a'
```

But like I said, the makefile *should* already take care of everything, including installing the correct library in the correct place when you do e.g. `make install`.

For information about `libtool`, see [this site](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the additional information too! Very useful :) And yes I found out that the makefile did actually build the libraries, just not in the same folder ;) They were build to a locale folder of the file system. Thank you for the help :)